# Application under a site in IIS evaluates ~ to the website root not the virtual directory

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, windows

I have a website in IIS lets call it **QA.local**. Under this root site I want to set up multiple applications that reside in a set of virtual directories E.G. **QA.local/app1** and **QA.local/app2**. The problem is that whenever an application goes to resolve the ~ symbol the server returns the website root rather than the directory which hosts application so **QA.local/page.aspx** instead of the correct path **QA.local/app1/page.aspx**. Am I missing something basic in the config here or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 'Applications' rather than 'Virtual Directories' for your asp.net sites.

In IIS Manager you can right click your virtual directory and 'Convert to Application'.

Virtual Directories are just pointers to other locations within the same application, in this case the root application.

Applications are their own unit of execution, or app domains in dot.NET, to use the tilde (~) and other features of ASP.net you need to use an application.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried and it didn't work. If I browsed the url manually if renders so the application itself is in the right spot. I found a work around for our environment so I'll go ahead and mark this as the answer because I'm guessing in most other cases where this is happening that this is the fix. Thanks!